# GraphQL: Is changing a mutation parameter to accept null values considered a breaking-change?

Tags: api, graphql

TL;DR
One specific argument in my mutation definition is now configured as `String, required: true` which makes it a non-null mandatory string parameter. is changing it to `String, required: :nullable` considered a breaking change, and can possibly break clients of the API?

---

I have a backend with Ruby on rails using graphql. this is one of the defined mutations (just an example):

```
class Mutations::UpdatePerson < Mutations::BaseMutation
  argument :id, Integer, "The person's unique identifier.", required: true
  argument :name, String, "The new name of the person.", required: true

  type Types::PersonType
end
```

a client for this API might have an invocation definition for this mutation, like this:

```
mutation change_someone($new_name: String!){
  update_person(id:118607869, name: $new_name) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

I want to make the `name` parameter non-mandatory. I still want the mutation invocation to demand specifying the variable by it's name (`name`) but would like to also accept null values explicitly. so allowing this: `update_person(id:118607869, name: null)`, but NOT this: `update_person(id:118607869)`.

After reading up here: [documentation](https://graphql-ruby.org/fields/arguments.html#default-values) I managed to achieve this behaviour by changing my mutation definition like so:

```
class Mutations::UpdatePerson < Mutations::BaseMutation
  argument :id, Integer, "The person's unique identifier.", required: true
  argument :name, String, "The new name of the person.", required: :nullable

  type Types::PersonType
end
```

This is working as expected, but my general question is- **is there any possibility that this will actually break client code, for API consumers that already have defined requests with parameters and signatures (as described above) ?**

---

According to the graphql spec:

> As GraphQL type system schema evolves over time by adding new types and new fields, it is possible that a request which was previously valid could later become invalid. Any change that can cause a previously valid request to become invalid is considered a breaking change.

I tried all sorts of declaration variations using a graphql API playground, but could not make it break (i.e. turn red with "compilation" errors).
In my opinion, expanding the list of possible input values should not be considered a breaking change, but I just want to be 100% certain. (would settle for 99.999%)

Comment: You question is not consistent: You say you want to make `name` not mandatory (which is backwards compatible), but not accept mutations that don't explicitly define a value for it. Even if you allow null, this technically makes `name` required, and adding a  required parameter is a breaking change. Clients that currently send requests without explicitly specifying `name` (not even setting it to null) will get an error and break.

Comment: Thanks @LordOfThePigs, but the situation today as I stated above is that the `name` parameter is required, a mandatory string. so all current clients have to already have it specified in their API calls. so considering that, is my upcoming change, a breaking change?

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be. Since all your existing clients are providing a non-null value for `name` that means that no client is omitting the `name` variable altogether.

If OTOH you made a nullable parameter non-nullable then that would almost certainly be a breaking change.